# Do I need a database to save a finite set of data, and only for the current session in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a calculator type app, three different views to perform three different types of calculations. For example purposes lets say it's just a multiplication table.

I want to be able to enter the factors, have the products update, then submit the view back to the model so I (hopefully) give it to a pdf converter (probably HiQPdf) and print it out that way.

So far I've gotten the view to show with some default values but when I submit everything it resets to those same default values. I realize this is cause by a serious gap in my knowledge of how the whole HTTP thing works, but any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Tons of options. You may save them locally (local storage or cookies). You may send them back to server. You can save them in sessions. You may simply...do not refresh page but ask server for calculation and update page with results (using Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data, at least in the Session, once the session ends, all data is lost, but while working in the site, is stays there. On the post action, you'll have to put the data in the Session[] and in your view you have to get the Session data and display it.

Answer (score 0):

If the views just "repost" to themselves over and over as the user enters each new input you can create a ViewModel to hold all inputs, and just pass it back and forth, as opposed to 'storing' this data anywhere. (This could be as simple as a List, or you could make it much more intricate with the operation being performed, etc.)